# "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" - how to find these cycles?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, azure-sql-database, cascading-deletes

I was trying to modify foreign key in Azure SQL database to add `ON DELETE CASCADE`. I got error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Foo_Bar' on table 'Foo' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

How can I find cycle that prevent me from specyfing `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: Read [here](http://www.csharpcity.com/2011/finding-circular-dependencies-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Interesting, but returns only two cycles in totally other part of application.

Comment: @lad2025 link is dead.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva Please check [way back machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140322230011/http://www.csharpcity.com/2011/finding-circular-dependencies-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @lad2025 oh yeah thanks for reminding me. Totally forgot about that. :)

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/).